# Sobel method on data points

Tags: convolution, image-processing

From what I've seen of the Sobel method, one takes an source image $A$, and applies the matrices
$G_x =
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 && -2 && -1 \\
0 && 0 && 0 \\
1 && 2 && 1
\end{pmatrix} \star A$
and
$G_x =
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 && 0 && 1 \\
-2 && 0 && 2 \\
-1 && 0 && 1
\end{pmatrix} \star A$, where $\star$ represents a convolution. My question is, what exactly is "$A$"? Is it represented by the coordinates of the a pixel? If so, given that one has an image in $2d$, then the two matrices above can't act on it; so that can't be right. In articles I've read, it often says that one acts on an "image function" $I(x,y)$. But what does this function look like; does it have a well-defined form?

Comment: $A$ is just a 2-D matrix of the pixel values. I don't understand your other misgivings.

Comment: How does one have a 3-D matrix acting on a 2-D matrix? @AnonSubmitter85

Comment: What 3-D matrix? $A$, $G_x$, and $G_y$ are all 2-D. It sounds like you are confused as to what a 2-D convolution is. I'd suggest you search for a video that will help you visualize what is going on.

Comment: The 3-D matrices to which I refer are the ones with $-1, -2, 1,$ and $2$ as elements, the ones that act on $A$ by convolution. How do those matrices act on a 2-D matrix A?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 You also mentioned a video. Do you have a link?

Comment: Those are 2-D matrices (which have size $3 \times 3$) not 3-D. As for the video, just search for one; there must be dozens.